# Can a check in a table check if there is an attribute is at a column of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, consulta and especialidade :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sbd`.`especialidade` (
  `especialidade` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`especialidade`))

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sbd`.`consulta` (
  `Especialidade_especialidade` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT `fk_Consulta_Especialidade1`
   FOREIGN KEY (`Especialidade_especialidade`)
   REFERENCES `sbd`.`especialidade` (`especialidade`),

  CHECK(`Especialidade_especialidade` in (`sbd`.`especialidade` 
(`especialidade`)))
)
```

But this does't work.
I need to know if the attribute `Especialidade_especialidade` of table consulta is in the column `especialidade` of table especialidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a *foreign key* relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sbd.consulta (
    Especialidade_especialidade VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(Especialidade_especialidade) REFERENCES sbd.especialidade(especialidade))
```

You may omit mentioning the column `especialidade` in the table `especialidade` because that table has defined `especialidade` as its primary key, which makes it the default column referenced.

Note that naming a table and column the same will probably result in confusion all around. Prefer naming the primary key column (in all tables) simply `id`.

Comment: @AdathSkyderson What do you mean "doesn't work". It must work.

Comment: I just need to know if Especialidade_especialidade is a especialidade of table especialidade

Comment: Error: Error Code: 3814. An expression of a check constraint 'consulta_chk_1' contains disallowed function: `sbd`.`especialidade`.

Comment: imagine I have "B" and "A" at the table especialidade in especialidade. How can I have the name of especiality "B" in a check in table consulta?

Comment: like CHECK(SELECT `name` FROM `sbd`.`especialidade` WHERE `especialidade` = `B`) = "SOFIA"